# Create simple input field with autoform in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

Right now I have multiple filters

```
<template name="filter1">
  {{> selectFilter fieldName=fieldName options=options}}
</template>

<template name="filter2">
  {{> selectFilter fieldName=fieldName options=options}}
</template>

<template name="filter3">
  {{> selectFilter fieldName=fieldName options=options}}
</template>

<template name="filter4">
  {{> selectFilter fieldName=fieldName options=options}}
</template>

<template name="selectFilter">
  <select name="{{fieldName}}" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Any</option>
    {{#each options}}
      <option value="{{value}}" selected="{{#if sessionEquals ../fieldName value}}selected{{/if}}">{{label}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
</template>
```

which I populate with

```
Template.filter1.helpers( {
  fieldName: 'fieldName',
  options: getOptions
} );

Template.selectFilter.helpers( {
  sessionEquals: function ( key, value ) {
    return Session.equals( key, value );
  }
} );

Template.selectFilter.events( {
  'change select': function ( event ) {
    var $el = $( event.currentTarget );
    var variableName = $el.attr( 'name' );
    var value = $el.val();

    if ( isInt( value ) ) {
      value = parseInt( value, 10 );
    }

    Session.set( variableName, value );
  },
} );
```

With `collection2`, I have set `options` with:

```
field1: {
  type: Number,
  optional: true,
  autoform: {
    options: getOptionsForField1,
  },
},
```

Is it possible to use `autoform` and `collection2` to create a simple `select` element already populated with options without creating the html myself and populate the template with options?

I guess I can do something like `{{> quickField name=fieldName }}`, but I don't know how to tell from which schema it should look, and how to react on select change.

I just think it seems stupid of me to both specify the options in my schema and also populate the options to the template. This should be done automatically.

Comment: The short answer is yes, I will provide an example shortly

Answer (score 0):

Your AutoForm:

```
{{#autoForm collection="Collection" id=insertCollection type="insert"}}
    {{> afQuickField name='field1'}}
{{/autoForm}}
```

Your SimpleSchema:

```
Collection = new Mongo.Collection('collection');
Collection.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    field1: {
        type: Number,
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            options: function() {
                return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
            },
            type: "select"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you creating an insert form?

Comment: Well, you did not specify so I just used `insert`.